# What scope to service component

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I'm developing a java web application where I'm using spring like application container and vaadin like web framework. I'm new of spring and now I have some concerns about the scope of a few component. In my application I don't use spring MVC, but I have my business logic in a service layer. Now I try to explain better my situation with an example.

If I have to process some objects and then save the content of these objects I will have:

**Vaadin Panel**

```
public class ImportaCustomersPanel extends BasePanel{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;


    private Button importButton;

    private List<MyObject> objectToProcess;

    @Autowired
    ImportService importService;


    public ImportaClientiSitiContrattiPanel() {
        super();
        Injector.inject(this);
        //Other Components
        addListenes();

    }



    @SuppressWarnings("serial")
    private Button makeButtonEsporta() {

        importButton = new Button();
        importButton.addClickListener(new ClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void buttonClick(ClickEvent event) {
                    importService.process(objectToProcess);

            }
        });
    }
}
```

**Spring Service**

```
@Service
public class ImportServiceImpl implements ImportService {

    @Autowired
    CustomerRepository customerRepository;

    @Autowired
    CustomerDetailsRepository customerDetailsRepository;

    @Transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW,rollbackFor=Exception.class)
    public ImportClienteSitiContrattiDTO process(List<MyObject> objectToProcess) throws Exception {
        //I apply some business rule and persist the entities
        customerRepository.save(objectToProcess.save(0));
        customerDetailsRepository.save(objectToProcess.save(1));


    }

}
```

Now from spring reference documentation i read the following sentences:

> As a rule, use the prototype scope for all stateful beans and the singleton scope for stateless beans.

Then I transate this sentences in this way:

If my bean(in this case it is a service) has some variables with scope at level class

```
    public class ImportServiceImpl implements ImportService {

    @Autowired
    CustomerRepository customerRepository;

    @Autowired
    CustomerDetailsRepository customerDetailsRepository;

    private List<MyObject> objectToProcess;

    @Transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW,rollbackFor=Exception.class)
    public ImportClienteSitiContrattiDTO process(List<MyObject> objectToProcess) throws Exception {

        this.objectToProcess = objectToProcess
        //I apply some business rule and persist the entities
        customerRepository.save(objectToProcess.save(0));
        customerDetailsRepository.save(objectToProcess.save(1));


    }

}
```

in this case the scope should be prototype, because many client could share the state of this service. Instead in first definition of service class I could have used a singleton scope because that bean doesn't contains the state.

Is this true?
What are the best practice to following to assing a scope?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would make the service stateless and let it be singleton.

Note that if `customerRepository` and `customerDetailsRepository` are stateless themselves then you just need to remove `objectToProcess` in order to make the class stateless.

You have to choose a scope whether or not you use Spring. The common approach it to avoid sharing state and use stateless classes as much as possible.

A service is usually a stateless thing - it is just a collection of methods that let you communicate with another part of your app (or another app).